# Как распространять программу с зависимостями?

Tags: python

Как распространять программу на питоне чтобы у пользователей устанавливались все требуемые модули, в т.ч. бинарные на винде?

Все программы на питоне которые я видел распространялись через py2exe & co. По нескольким причинам мне хотелось бы чтобы модули ставились в систему. Во-первых, размер (PySide, напрмер, весит метров 100, его придется перекачивать при каждом апдейте), во-вторых, программу в бандле нельзя нормально отлаживать.

Может возникнуть желание использовать определенную версию библиотеки, но не более позднюю.

Comment: А [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) вас не устраивает? Или вы пишите что-то для других и пользователь не должен плясать с бубном, чтобы запустить вашу программу?

Comment: Тут вроде все основные варианты разжеваны: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558385/how-can-i-distribute-python-programs если кто скомбинирует и переведет будет отлично.

Comment: @BOPOH да, это для пользователей.

Comment: @PetrAbdulin "I'd probably recommend that you distribute it with disutils for Linux, and Py2exe or something similar for Windows. " - см. правку

Comment: @PetrAbdulin Сейчас обратил внимание - ответы 2009 года. Кагбэ зачем такое советовать?

Comment: @SmitJohnth пфф!

Comment: Если приложение не является инструментом для разработчиков, то пользователя не должно волновать какой язык реализации Вы используете. Используйте формат привычный для платформы: Windows/Mac App Store; Ubuntu ppa, exe-установщик на Винде, пакеты rpm, deb на Linux. Все эти инструменты встроенные средства обновления имеют. В качестве примера можно посмотреть в каких форматах VLC распространяется, который возможно даже на кофеварках может работать.

Comment: Для *разработчиков* можно conda рекомендовать, чтобы пакет с  бинарными зависимостями (не чистый Питон) ставить и всегда опция `pip install` должна быть (из исходников и/или бинарных wheels (Windows, OSX). В качестве примера [`pandas` пакет можно использовать.](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html)

Comment: @jfs но зачем таскать с собой все библиотеки? Неужели нельзя это обойти? Почему все работает на прыщах? Привычный формат - это когда на линупсе пакетный менеджер юзаем, а на венде все хреначим в зборочку, хоть pip на венде тоже есть? Тем более, красноглазы разродились wheel.

Answer (score 2):

Рекомендую [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org) для этого. Особенно сейчас, когда появилась полноценная поддержка `Python 3`. При сборке PyInstaller не тянет за собой весь PyQt или PySide, а только те части, которые импортируются в программе. Таким образом, моё небольшое приложение, в котором я делаю следующие импорты, весит немногим более 15-ти мегабайт:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
```

Устанавливается PyInstaller просто:

```
pip install PyInstaller
```

Затем я собираю свое приложение следующим образом:

```
c:\Python34\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe -p C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages -F app.py
```

Здесь опция `-p` для указания директории, где находятся импортируемые модули, `-F` для сборки в единственный exe-файл.
Подробнее можно почитать в [документации](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/).

P.S. Ну и понятное дело, он кроссплатформенный.